# How can I get these html elements to position and stagger correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have web page that has a collection of tiled elements as a background. Positioned above this, I have another set of tiles (that are twice as large) acting as an overlay. Each of these larger tiles has a 'margin-right' equal to the size of one of the smaller background tiles. You can see an example of this @ http://jsfiddle.net/dhx2r/2/ *updated

At first glance this displays correctly. The problem is that due to each larger tile having this right margin, it means if you expand the window, a tile won't slide up to fill the gap unless it's larger than 3 small tiles wide. (like this: http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/1412/70953496.png)

Ideally I'd somehow attach to the window.resize event and set the 'margin-right' to '0' when a gap of 3 small tiles becomes available. I tried to do this with the code in the js panel of jsfiddle yet it didn't give the correct results. Since the code I'm using relies on the 'window.resize' event, the jsfiddle doesn't demonstrate what actually happens but it at least shows the code I'm using.

I've been struggling with this problem for ~7 hours today so my mind is a little fried! My intention after fixing this initial problem was to then somehow stagger the odd rows so they have a 'margin-left' of the width of the small tiles, to give this effect: http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/3600/57663338.png

I managed to calculate even/odd rows using (assuming small tiles were 150px and large 300px):

```
if ((pos != 0) && (pos % 600 != 0)) {
    // The row is even, stagger the tiles.
}
else {
    // The row is odd, do nothing.
}
```

.. however I never got past this inital problem to work on the logic.

Anyway if anyone has a solution on how I can get this working I'd greatly appreciate it! I feel like I've wasted a whole day banging my head against a wall.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a beginning of the solution but sometimes the color is not set correctly. I'm searching to resolve it.

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/dhx2r/11/)

Finally all problems are solved [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/dhx2r/13/).

Thanks you, it was funny for me to find asolution. I hope this solution is good for you.

Comment: My hero! Thanks so much Charles... I've been pulling my hair out all week trying to figure this out!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should ditch the margin and use some hidden filler tiles that collapse just like the large ones?

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhx2r/1/)***

Okay, part 2.  This is a solution needs tweaking, and I've colored even rows orange for testing.  I don't have time to fiddle with the exact numbers, but this should get you very close.

***[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dhx2r/6/)***

Comment: This is actually a great idea, thanks. The only problem is that I always want the even rows staggered. If you resize the window you'll see that sometimes the large tiles are perfectly aligned...

Comment: Ah, that's trickier.  Sorry for missing part 2.  I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @alimac83 I've updated my solution. You will have to play with the numbers a little to get it perfect.